# Why does cargo profiler show info for C code?

Tags: linux, rust, profiling

I am using [cargo profiler](https://github.com/svenstaro/cargo-profiler) to seek bottlenecks in my Rust project and I get information that looks like this:

```
Total Instructions...1,592,646

85,626 (5.4%) dl-lookup.c:do_lookup_x
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
66,838 (4.2%) vfscanf-internal.c:__vfscanf_internal
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
66,742 (4.2%) dl-addr.c:_dl_addr
```

These functions come from some C libraries and is not very insightful.

The tools documentation shows examples for Rust source code:

```
Total Instructions...198,466,456

78,346,775 (39.5%) dgemm_kernel.rs:matrixmultiply::gemm::masked_kernel
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
23,528,320 (11.9%) iter.rs:_..std..ops..Range..A....as..std..iter..Iterator..::next
```

How can I make `cargo profile` give information that points to Rust source code, not to C code?

Comment: That's probably because your program spends most of its time in those C functions. Since `cargo profiler` relies on valgrind, it should have generated a `callgrind.out.<pid>` file and you can use the [`callgrind_annotate`](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) to get backtraces that hopefully will include the calling Rust functions.

Comment: Using Valgrind and Kcachegrind directly points straight to my Rust code.

Comment: Maybe open an issue on the repo itself?